# html href link that runs mysqli command onclick

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a link in a  in a table that links to a little tooltip.

```
<th><a href="#" class="tooltip">Reg NSB$
```

This works fine, but I'd like the link to resort the table by that column when it's click (a common feature in web tables that I see...)  My initial thought was to put an onclick event there, like so:

```
<th><a href="#" class="tooltip" onclick="<?php mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM report WHERE PMName = '$PMSelection' AND REGNSB <> 0.000 ORDER BY RegNSB DESC Limit $LimitStart,$LimitItems"); ?>">Reg NSB$
```

I've looked around but I can't figure out a way to accomplish the running of a mysqli query when I click on a "link".

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot do this. You can run some JavaSctipt that performs an AJAX request to a PHP file that runs a MySQL query.

Comment: -1 As @JayBlanchard said, you cannot do this because HTML/JS run in a completely different environment (client computer) than your PHP/MYSQL (server).

Comment: Thank you for this - I will read up on this.  I don't know much about the difference between client and server sides.

Comment: The other option is to add query parameters to the link (`href="?sort[]=RegNSB"`), and then re-render the table with the table re-ordered.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following: Use jQuery to send an AJAX-request to the web-server as soon as a user clicks on that table header:

```
$(".tooltip").click({function(){
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "server/database.php",  //Set the correct path to the php-file residing on the server here
            data: {
                //Set any data you need to send to the server here
            },
            success : function(data){
                //Called when server responded with success-code
            },
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //Called when server responded with error-code
            }
        })
    });
```

Don't forget to wrap this code in the document.ready()-handler of jQuery. Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for further information about asynchronous calls

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  I didn't realize one was client side and one was server side.  I'll read up on this and see if I can't make it work.  Thanks!

Comment: Phew, this is quite a lot of new stuff.  I know nothing about jquery or ajax, but I see the words thrown around a lot.  Do you have any other good resources to read up on these?  Thanks again!

Comment: Before you start studying jQuery, you have to know that php is a purely server-side scripting language and javascript is totally executeded on the client. The fundamental understanding of the client-server paradigm is important here.
With that in mind you could read this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp